# Python UnicodeEncodeError and Email

Tags: python

I'm in way over my head.  Can someone please dumb this down for me??

I'm porting my code from Python 2.6 to 2.7 and suddenly I cannot retrieve my email payload anymore because of a unicode issue (it's literally pulling the same email, just using different Py versions.  I read the Unicode HOWTO and got lost.

The following works when run on Python 2.6:

```
response = server.fetch(messages, ['RFC822'])
for msgid, data in response.iteritems():
    msg_string = data['RFC822']
    msg = email.message_from_string(msg_string)   

    body = msg.get_payload()  
    abody = str(body[1])  #converts the HTML instance to a string
```

But when I run this under 2.7 I get the following error:

```
File "./foo.py", line 75, in main
  msg = email.message_from_string(msg_string)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/__init__.py", line 57, in message_from_string
  return Parser(*args, **kws).parsestr(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/parser.py", line 82, in parsestr
  return self.parse(StringIO(text), headersonly=headersonly)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3041: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So clearly the 2.7 interpreter doesn't like some part of the email I'm reading in.  And I suspect I need to convert the type (or somehow muck with output type), but I'm lost as to the true issue and solution.

I'm 2 hours into this and could use a helping hand.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess: your msg_string is encoded using UTF-8. It could also be further encoded as "quoted printable".

I would try doing something like this:

```
#...
msg_string = data['RFC822'].decode('utf8')
#...  etc
```

And if that helps, but you still see strange characters (=C3=96...), try the following:

```
import quopri
#...
msg_string = data['RFC822'].decode('quopri').decode('utf8')
#...  etc
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't make a difference.  On further inspection, it caused the error to get thrown earlier now.  Not sure if that helps explain the issue.  It's still the same error.  Here's what I get...
    File "./getAmex.py", line 250, in <module>
      main()
    File "./getAmex.py", line 70, in main
      msg_string = data['RFC822'].decode('utf8')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
      return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3029: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Sorry, couldnt figure out how to get the indent-4 to work on this code output.  :-(

Comment: I found there was one change to the email module in 2.7: [link](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html).  Specifically... The email module’s Message class will now accept a Unicode-valued payload, automatically converting the payload to the encoding specified by output_charset. 

The other thing I did was upgrade RFC822 to RFC2822 but that didn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: Can you post a sample value for msg_string that fails in 2.7 but works in 2.6? This way, we'll be able to test it for ourselves and figure out the solution.

Comment: Thanks.  Here's the sample file http://goo.gl/IIBqb.  FWIW... 'print type(msg_string)' returns 'unicode'.

Comment: Hi Orlenko.  Please let me know if I didn't give you everything you needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Orlenko, please disregard.  The problem is that the newest version of the imapclient returns email payload as some unicode type.  I just reverted to the older library and it all works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
msg_string = data['RFC822'].encode('ascii','ignore')
```